# How to create a directory structure with changing ownership using Ansible playbook

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

How to create below directory structure with below ownership using Ansible playbook?

root directory:

```
# 'apps/' is variable that need to give during running 'ansible-playbook'
/apps/
/ibl/
```

Under root directory below directory should create:

```
app
appsvr
pipe
log
dat
```

Under `app`, `log`, `dat` directories following directories should be created with below ownership:

```
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 23  2015 adm   
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_ath   ib0_q_ath   4096 Sep 23  2015 ath    
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_swt   ib0_q_swt   4096 Sep 23  2015 bkn    
drwxrwx---. 13 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 29  2015 cmn    
drwxrwx---.  6 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 29  2015 crd    
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 23  2015 frd    
drwxrwx---.  3 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 29  2015 rcn   
drwxrwx---.  4 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 29  2015 rpt
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_jboss ib0_q_jboss 4096 Sep 23  2015 sch    
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_swt   ib0_q_swt   4096 Sep 23  2015 sim    
drwxrwx---.  2 ib0_q_swt   ib0_q_swt   4096 Sep 23  2015 swt
```

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score -1):

Create yml entries for each directory e.g:

```
- name: Creates directory
  file:
    path: /apps/'{{ drctry }}'ansible-playbook/ibl/app/adm
    state: directory
    owner: ib0_q_swt
    group: ib0_q_swt
    mode: 0777
```

Where {{ drctry }} is the directory variable to be passed.

You would then set the variable with:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars "drctry=somedirectory"
```